# nginx rewrite 404 err

Tags: nginx, seo, url-rewriting

How it should work

1. frontend start page is `http://server/apex/` - dead page
2. redirect to work page, `to /apex/f?p=100:4:0::NO:::`
3. make clean url types  `http://server/apex/4/0/NO`

`location / {`

```
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    include /etc/nginx/reverse_proxy.conf;
    rewrite ^/$ /apex/f?p=100:4:0::NO:::? permanent;
       }

location  /apex {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    include /etc/nginx/reverse_proxy.conf;

    if ($args ~ "p=100:(.*):(.*)::(.*):::") {
                  set $args $1/$2/$3/$4;
                  rewrite ^/[a-z]+/.+ /apex/$args?;
                              }
        }
```

log from nginx  - access.log
"

```
GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-"
"GET /apex/f?p=100:4:0::NO::: HTTP/1.1" 404 5
```

from error log (debug)

```
[notice] 27639#0: *3 "^/$" matches "/", client: 222.222.222.222, server: server, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "server"
 [notice] 27639#0: *3 rewritten redirect: "/apex/f?p=100:4:0::NO:::", client: 222.222.222.222, server: server, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "server"
 [notice] 27639#0: *3 "p=100:(.*):(.*)::(.*):::" matches "p=100:4:0::NO:::", client: 222.222.222.222, server: server, request: "GET /apex/f?p=100:4:0::NO::: HTTP/1.1", host: "server"
 [notice] 27639#0: *3 "^/[a-z]+/.+" matches "/apex/f", client: 222.222.222.222, server: server, request: "GET /apex/f?p=100:4:0::NO::: HTTP/1.1", host: "server"
 [notice] 27639#0: *3 rewritten data: "/apex/4/0/NO", args: "", client: 222.222.222.222, server: server, request: "GET /apex/f?p=100:4:0::NO::: HTTP/1.1", host: "server"
 [notice] 27639#0: *3 "p=100:(.*):(.*)::(.*):::" does not match "", client: 222.222.222.222, server: server, request: "GET /apex/f?p=100:4:0::NO::: HTTP/1.1", host: "server"
```

What am I doing wrong?